# Route and Base tag not working correctly in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis

I have an angular.js application that will need to run in IIS. I have the  tag in my development machine and that machine runs the site under IISExpress and it works just fine. I have the following code in the global.asax per the Angular docs:

```
private const string ROOT_DOCUMENT = "/index.html";

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = Request.Url.LocalPath;
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Context.Server.MapPath(url)))
                Context.RewritePath(ROOT_DOCUMENT);
        }
```

My routing in my app.js is as follows:

```
JBenchApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'JBenchCtrl'
        }).
        when('/calendar', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/calendar.html',
            controller: 'JBenchCtrl'
        }).
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/calendar.html',
            controller: 'JBenchCtrl'
        }).
        when('/documents/:number', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/documents.html',
            controller: 'CaseDetailCtrl'
        }).
        when('/parties/:number', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/parties.html',
              controller: 'CaseDetailCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

I added the following to my web.config file:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

When I deploy to my server the application is actually at http://nameofserver/jwb so I change the  to be  and the problem that arises is it doesn't seem like Angular loads. None of my ng-click events fire, etc.

Remember, this works on IISExpress just fine.

How do I make the routing work here?

Comment: check the path of resource files loading in browser dev tools network. Show base tag. Likely need to set up web.config also for html5Mode but IIS is not my strength

Comment: It works fine in IISExpress just not IIS. Help? I get 404 errors like crazy

Comment: The 404s are likely angular (or templates) not loading - presumably due to some IIS configuration since you are not serving from the root context. Can you clarify your wording here: "so I change the to be and the problem that arises is it doesn't seem like Angular loads" so I change the ... to be ... ?